# Navbar won't move towards the right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My navbar wont go towards the right side. I set the div as you can see. However, div still is staying on the left side of the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BudLyfe</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if (!user_signed_in?) %>
            <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                    role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <%= current_user.email %> <span class="caret"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like bootstrap 4 uses utility classes for navbar spacing instead of the bootstrap 3 version of `navbar-right`. In the future, be sure you are looking at the correct documentation for the specific version of bootstrap that you are using.

Using `ml-auto` in place of `navbar-right` pushes that list to the right side of the navbar. This `ml-auto` class stands for `margin-left: auto;` which is the individual css rule you would use to achieve this effect without bootstrap.

Example codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzBKPe

Comment: wow you are the best. Thank you so much!